# [svm]A Problem of $\max(1/\|w\|)$ equal to $\min(1/2\cdot \|w\|^2)$

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, vector-analysis

I've been search many SVM theory thesis for machine learning
Those articles usually say $\max(1/\|w\|)$ equal to $\min(1/2\cdot \|w\|^2)$
but they didn't write the detail of the mathematics process.
I also read this
[Why is max($\frac{2}{||w||}$)= min($\frac{1}{2}$)($||w||^2$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773847/why-is-max-frac2w-min-frac12w2)

I still can't figure out.

thanks

Comment: It's not. However, the argument $w$ which maximizes the first expression is the same as the argument which minimizes the second. To make the first exression large, you must make $||w||$ small, and squaring that term makes no difference, as it is a monotonic operation.

Comment: THx for your answer,I knew that ||w|| need to be minimize,but why ||w|| will turn to be 1/2*||w||^2,What's mean  monotonic operation?

Comment: Are there any mathematics theory between they?

Comment: Not much to theorize around. If $x$ is small then $1/x$ is large. $f$ being monotonic means $f(x)>f(y)$ when $x > y$.

Comment: THX! I got it !